# In c, is there an equivalent of "+=" for "p = p->next"?

Tags: c, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm currently learning C and am now at the part of structs and lists.
I just wondered, if there ist something like "a = a+b" = "a += b" for this case.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: do you mean to say adding structure variables with other same structure variable?

Comment: There is no such shortcut in any programming language that I know of.

Comment: No, how would that look anyway? `p ->= next`? Not really more readable than `p = p->next`.

Comment: `p = p->next` clearly requires compile-time knowledge there is a `next` member within whatever structure `p` refers. What if I called mine `fore` ?

Comment: Please don't tag both C and C++.

Comment: @TanveerBadar And please don't remove the C++ tag once there are C++ answers posted. See C and C++ tag usage in the tag wikis. I did a rollback.

Comment: What's wrong with `p = p->next`? It's perfectly readable code, to the point where it could be considered canonical C.

Comment: @Lundin nothing, I was just interested.

Comment: I just came across this question on another site and remembered this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28874

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++ then instead of the raw pointers you could define your own class of iterator for a list that internally contained the pointer `p`.

In this case you could substitute the expression

```
p = p->next;
```

for the expression

```
++it;
```

that under the hood will do `p = p->next`.

Something like

```
iterator & operator ++()
{
    iterator::p = iterator::p->next;
    return *this;
}
```

where the pointer `p` is a data member of the class `iterator`.

As for the compound assignment operator then there are no such operators like `->=` or `.=`. So you can not overload them.

According to C and C++ Standards the assignment operator is one of

```
= *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= &= ^= |=
```

Answer (score 0):

No.
You could use a macro, but i wouldn't.